# RaphaelJS - Hover - show/hide seperate DIV

Tags: javascript, show

I'm a true newbie when it comes to RaphaelJS so forgive me for some basic questions.

I'm trying to implement a interactive map to my website and heard RaphaelJS was the best option to accomplish this. However it's not currently working in my favor. I found a map on github and right now I'm tinkering with it so A, I have a better understanding of what needs to be done. B, I can write out working code before I dive in.

What I'm trying to accomplish. When a user hover's over a state, a div is shown (in this case the div called box in CSS). I know how to accomplish this in JQUERY.

`$("CA").hover(function(){ $(".box").show();`

However this is not working in the JS writeup. More then likely because I'm pulling a Raphael object??

Here is the jsfiddle to the map and code.

http://jsfiddle.net/b3vLx8uh/1/

html

```
<div id="rsr"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

css

```
#rsr {
    width: 615px;
    height: 500px;
}

.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
}
```

(check JSfiddle for JS code)

I'm stuck, trying to figure this out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use Raphaël for this, you can just use vanilla JS (or jQuery if you load that library too).

```
el.mouseover(function () {
    document.getElementById('myHoverContents').style.display = 'block'; //show the div
    this.toFront();
    this.attr({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        fill: 'black',
        stroke: '#fff',
            'stroke-width': '2',

    });
    this.animate({
        scale: '1.2'
    }, 200);
});
el.mouseout(function () {
    document.getElementById('myHoverContents').style.display = 'none'; //hide the div
    this.animate({
        scale: '1.05'
    }, 200);
    this.attr({
        fill: '#003366'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3vLx8uh/3/

Comment: Glad to hear it! If this solved your issue, please check the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks!